# Why pybind11 converts double to int?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I created .pyd file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
namespace py = pybind11;
int add(int num) {
    float a = 1.0;  
    for (int i = 0; i <= num; i = i + 1) {
        a = (a + i)/a;
    }        
    std::cout << "dll is typing: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;
    return a;
}
PYBIND11_MODULE(py_dll, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 py_dll plugin"; // optional module docstring
    m.def("add", &add, "Add function", py::arg("num"));
}
```

I call it from python:

```
import py_dll
num = 500
a = py_dll.add(num)
print ('python is typing: ', a)
```

It prints:

[image]

Why digit became int? I speak about 22. I expect it to be float 22.8722

Comment: forget about pybind for a moment, then what does `add` return? Its not a float, is it?

Comment: @idclev463035818, mmmm.... I expect it returns float. Because variable a is float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function

```
int add(int num)
```

takes an `int` as parameter and returns an `int`. The "problem" is not with pybind. Try this to see:

```
int main() {
    auto x = add(42);
    std::cout << "return value: " << x << '\n';
    std::cout << typeid(x).name() << std::endl;
}
```

If the function should return a `float` you have to declare that it returns a `float`:

```
float add(int num)
```